# How can I create a network load on my local WIFI with only one PC?

Tags: networking, vmware

I have tried to load my local Wi-Fi with a win 11 machine, WINSCP SFTP Client and a virtual machine on the same PC running an SFTP server with another IP address (bridged LAN, same Subnet, different IP Address). Of course, this works, but the traffic never goes out of the Wi-Fi adapter and the Wi-Fi stays unloaded. Is there a command (switch, parameter) available, that forces a "local" packet to be transmitted to the access point and received again, so I can see the UL&DL load on the Network monitor?
Thanks in advance